# I have Op class that have a list which must contain only one typ of class or his subclasses(only A class,his subclass OR only class Band his subclass)

Tags: java, generics

I have following code:

```
class A {}
class Aa extendes A {}
class B {}
class Bb extendes B {}
class Op {
 private List objects = new ArrayList();
 
 public void addObj(Object o) {
  objects.add(o);
 }
}

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] srgs) {
  A a1 = new A();
  Aa a2 = new Aa();
  B b1 = new B();
  Bb b2 = new Bb();

  Op op = new Op();
  op.addObj(a1); \\ should be OK
  op.addObj(a2); \\ should be OK
  op.addObj(b1); \\ should be compilation error
 }
}
```

I need change "Op" class in order to B and Bd classes can't be placed in objects(List) if A and Aa have been already placed there and vice versa. Solution with generics.

I try this:

```
class Op <T> {
 private List<? extends T> objects = new ArrayList();

 public void addObj(T<? extends T> o) { //compilation error here 
  objects.add(o); // and here 
 }
}
```

But it doens't work. May you help me please. Thanks!

Comment: "op.addObj(a3); \\ should be compilation error" <- I'm 100% sure that it already is a compoilation error because nowhere in your code is there any variable defined with the name of `a3` so you'll get a very old school "Symbol not found" or "cannot be resolved to a variable" compilation error.

Comment: a) `List` and `ArrayList` are raw types, stop using them. b) what is `T<? extends T>`? Don't you just mean `T`, which already only accepts the type and subtypes but no other types c) your list can be a `List<T>` too, probably; you don't gain anything by defining it with a wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Op<T> {
    private List<T> objects = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addObj(T o) {
        objects.add(o);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        Aa a2 = new Aa();
        B b1 = new B();
        Bb b2 = new Bb();

        Op<A> opA = new Op<>();
        opA.addObj(a1); // OK
        opA.addObj(a2); // OK
        // opA.addObj(b1); // Compilation error

        Op<B> opB = new Op<>();
        opB.addObj(b1); // OK
        opB.addObj(b2); // OK
        // opB.addObj(a1); // Compilation error
    }
}

class A {}
class Aa extends A {}
class B {}
class Bb extends B {}
```

In this implementation, the `Op` class is parameterized with a type parameter `T` and the list `objects` is declared with `T` type too. This allows you to add objects **only of type `T`**.

The `addObj` method takes an argument of type `T`, which is the type parameter of the `Op` class. This method can now be used to add **only objects of type `T`** to the list.

### Edit

> Why subtypes are accepted for T parameter? I mean why we write  instead of <? extends T>. If I correctly understand the last statement is a boundary that defines allow to add subclasses.

Well, when you define a class with a generic type parameter, like `Op<T>`, you are creating a class that can operate on different types.

The type parameter `T` itself **doesn't inherently carry any constraints**. When you instantiate the class with a specific type argument, such as `Op<A>` or `Op<B>`, you are essentially telling Java to work with that particular type.

In the context of your example, consider `Op<A> opA`. While the class definition doesn't include any wildcards or type bounds, the compiler knows that `opA` can only contain objects of type `A` or its subclasses, due to the way the `Op` class is defined and instantiated.

If you used `Op<? extends A>`, it would indeed allow you to insert subclasses of `A` into the list, but **it would also restrict other operations** you might want to perform on `opA`. For example, you might not be able to add objects of type `A` itself to the list since the wildcard would be more permissive.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `? super T` instead of just `T`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're right! I improved my question.

Comment: @DiegoBorba, thank you. You really helped me. Could you answer one question please?
Why subtypes are accepted for T parameter? I mean why we write <T> instead of <? extends T>. If I correctly understand the last statement is a boundary that defines allow to add subclasses. I hope you understand my question. Thanks!

Comment: I was writing a comment but it gets too long, so I put it on the answer. I hope it helps!